How do I calculate the axial spring constant of a non-uniform cross section beam which is axially loaded?
How do I calculate the axial spring constant of a non-uniform cross section beam which is axially loaded?
I know that for uniform cross section beam, the axial spring constant is:
$$k_\text{axial}=\frac{EA}{L}$$
Should I just express area as a function and integrate it from 0 to L?
Please help.

You should try and use MathJax for equations instead of images. Depending on the device not everybody can see images, whereas MathJax will almost-always render.
